# How to undo a popFront a range

Tags: d, range

What is the standard way to "undo" a `popFront` operation? I realize that this would not work on all ranges, but for things like arrays, say you had

```
int[] a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

And you did `a.popFront()` which would adjust the start pointer of `a` to point at the `2`, how would you undo that operation to get back the `1` in the range? I am aware of `std.container.insertFront` but that is not the operation I am looking for.

I have tried

```
a = a[1..$];
a = a[-1..$];
```

but the second line throws a `RangeError`. Also, arrays support slicing, but the method I am looking for should support non-random-access ranges and ranges that do not support slicing. So even if `a[-1..$]` did work, it wouldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't undo `popFront`. You can't even do something equivalent to `arr[-1 .. $]` with arrays. If you want the old version, you have to save it first.

```
auto saved = range.save;
range.popFront();
range = saved; // "undo" popFront()
```

Arrays do not provide any more functionality than that either. To do the same thing with arrays without the range API, you'd have to do something like

```
auto saved = arr;
arr = arr[1 .. $];
arr = saved;
```

The *only* way to "undo" a pop operation on a range or array is to save it first and then use the old version. Nothing else is provided by either the range API or by arrays. They do not save their state on their own (and therefore could not know how to undo a previous operation), and not even array slices have any idea what data may be before or after them in memory (and trying to access the memory before or after an array would be illegal as you saw when you hit a `RangeError`).

So, if you have to worry about "undoing" the popping off of an arbitrary number of elements, then you're probably going to have to have to do something like hold onto the original range and keep track of how many elements you've popped of it so that you can pop off that number of elements minus the number of levels of "undo" that you want. And while not much copying is likely to be going on here (for arrays, it would just be multiple slices pointing to the same memory but in different places in it), if you're not dealing with a range with slicing, all of that popping off could be expensive (as could holding a saved version of the range from before each element is popped off), especially if you were trying to undo one level at a time, so the range API may not be very well suited to what you're trying to do, and you may have to rethink how you're go about it.

Comment: I guess "random-access" range should be replaced with "bidirectional range" in your answer, shouldn't it?

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун Actually, what it should be replaced with is a range with slicing. If you keep track of how many elements you want to unpop, then you can grab a new slice from the original with the elements that you want in O(1), whereas if don't have that, you'd have to pop off all of the elements again one by one, so it would be O(n). But I don't see how bidirectional ranges would factor into that, since we're talking about undoing popping elements off of the front. Popping elements off of the back won't help you any.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was sure bidirectional range is random-access range with O(n) element access (not two ends to pop from but two directions to move from front). Somewhat misleading name, but shame on me.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way would be to save a copy of the range before popping. Popping is a destructive mutation, and the range is free to deallocate the element, rebalance the underlying tree, or otherwise invalidate the previous element.

Thus:

```
MyRange old = current.save;
current.popFront();
if (current.front == magicValue) {
    current = old;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be inconvenient. If I need to go back possibly from 0 to _n_ elements, I've got to save _n_ ranges if the range isn't random access.

Comment: @Johm then copy it into an array first

Comment: Please note that you are not strictly copying the array, rather the pointer to the array. In other words, changing a value in the second range will change the one in the first. No duplication occurs.